# How to encrypt a merged pdfdocument properly

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I have a problem with the pdfBox API. Im trying to encrypt a merged pdfdocument with the following code:

This is the function to merge / create the doc

```
    public static void fillMultipleReportsInOne(List<report> reports) throws IOException {

        PDFMergerUtility PDFmerger = new PDFMergerUtility(); 
        PDDocument resultPDF = new PDDocument();

        for (report report : reports) {

            try 
            {
                PDDocument pdfDocument = PDDocument.load(new File(SRC + "test.pdf"));
                // get the document catalog
                PDAcroForm acroForm = pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();

                // as there might not be an AcroForm entry a null check is necessary
                setFormFields(acroForm, report.getName(), report.getArea(), report.getOperatingActivities(), report.getVocationlaSchool(), report.getWeeklyTopics());
                // Save and close the filled out form.
                PDFmerger.appendDocument(resultPDF, pdfDocument);



        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    encryptPDF(resultPDF, SRC + "merged.pdf");

}
```

And this is the function to encrypt:

```
 public static PDDocument encryptPDF(PDDocument pddocumentToEncrypt, String SRC) {

        // Define the length of the encryption key.
        // Possible values are 40 or 128 (256 will be available in PDFBox 2.0).
        int keyLength = 128;

        AccessPermission ap = new AccessPermission();

        // Disable printing, everything else is allowed
        ap.setCanModifyAnnotations(false);
        ap.setCanFillInForm(false);
        ap.setCanModify(false);


        // Owner password (to open the file with all permissions) is "12345"
        // User password (to open the file but with restricted permissions, is empty here) 
        StandardProtectionPolicy spp = new StandardProtectionPolicy("12334", "", ap);
        spp.setEncryptionKeyLength(keyLength);
        spp.setPermissions(ap);
        try {
            pddocumentToEncrypt.protect(spp);
            pddocumentToEncrypt.save(SRC);
            pddocumentToEncrypt.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return pddocumentToEncrypt;
    }
```

And finally the call of the function with all the sample data

```
report report1 = new report("TestUser1", "P&T", "operatingActivities", "weeklyTopics","vocationalSchool");
        report report2 = new report("TestUser2", "P&T2", "operatingActivities2", "weeklyTopics2","vocationalSchool2");
        report report3 = new report("TestUser3", "P&T3", "operatingActivities3", "weeklyTopics3","vocationalSchool3");
        report report4 = new report("TestUser4", "P&T4", "operatingActivities4", "weeklyTopics4","vocationalSchool4");

        List<report> reports = new ArrayList<>();
        reports.add(report1);
        reports.add(report2);
        reports.add(report3);
        reports.add(report4);

        fillMultipleReportsInOne(reports);
```

My outcome looks like this:

**OUTCOME**

[image]

Only the first field is filled with data, when all fields should have
It's definetely an encryption problem because when I delete the document.protect() line the data is filled correctly. I also tried the acroForm.flatten() function -> no success...

Maybe someone had the same issue and is willing to help :)
Thanks in advance
- Alex

Here's the entire file pasted in pastebin:
https://pastebin.com/L9auaTGH

With the code line

```
pddocumentToEncrypt.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().refreshAppearances();
```

inside my encryption function, it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling

```
pddocumentToEncrypt.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().refreshAppearances();
```

fixes this for the 2.0 version. That version doesn't set the appearence (i.e. the visual representation of the form value) in the `setValue()` call when /NeedAppearances is set (see `PDTerminalField.applyChange()`). The /NeedAppearances setting (when true) means that the viewing application should create the appearance so that processing applications in-between do not need to do so; I suspect that the one or several of the permission settings prevent Adobe Reader from changing it when displaying.

Another solution would be to call

```
pdfDocument.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm().setNeedAppearances(false);
```

before setting the form values.

The only unsolved mystery is why the first value was visible in the merged file.

Comment: *"The /NeedAppearances setting (when true) means that the application should create the appearance"* - more exactly it means that an application *needing appearances* (in particular *viewers*) should create new appearances so that *processing* applications in-between (without need for appearances) do not need to do so. In PDF 2.0 this point has become somewhat moot, though.

Comment: Thanks, I've included that one.